# How to make cash register total by allowing the user to insert the amount of cash into the list and the list is in the string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I want to make cash register total by allowing the user insert the amount of cash into the list. But It give me this error:

```
Purchase :12
Purchase :23
Purchase :12
Purchase :29.2
Purchase :11
Purchase :q
['12', '23', '12', '29.2', '11']
11.0
['12', '23', '12']
12.0
['12']
12.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Wan Afifi\Desktop\Python\append.py", line 17, in <module>
    add = float(purchase_amount.pop())
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

Here I attach my code. I wonder to know what the problem with my code? But here I have to do `.pop()` to complete the task.

```python
purchase_amount = []
x = 0

while True:
    purchase_amount1 = input("Purchase :")
    if purchase_amount1.upper() != "Q":
        purchase_amount.insert(x, purchase_amount1)
        x = x + 1
    else:
        break

print(purchase_amount)
subtotal = 0
while len(purchase_amount) != 0:
    print(float(purchase_amount.pop()))
    add = float(purchase_amount.pop())
    print(purchase_amount)
    subtotal = add + add

print(subtotal)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are popping an element from the list twice each loop iteration:

```
while len(purchase_amount) != 0:
    print(float(purchase_amount.pop()))
    add = float(purchase_amount.pop())
```

Unless you have an even number of elements in the list, that'll cause issues, as you don't *have* a second element to pop at the end.

You only need to pop *once*, and print the value you assigned to `add`:

```
while len(purchase_amount) != 0:
    add = float(purchase_amount.pop())
    print(add)
    # ...
```

The `!= 0` test is optional, because a non-zero integer value is considered 'true' in a boolean context such as a `while` condition. The `len()` call can also be removed, because a non-empty list is also considered true:

```
while purchase_amount:
    add = float(purchase_amount.pop())
    print(add)
    # ...
```

Next, you want to add the value to the collected total. You currently are replacing the `subtotal` variable each iteration with `add` added to itself:

```
while purchase_amount:
    add = float(purchase_amount.pop())
    subtotal = subtotal + add
```

Next, you don't really need to use `list.pop()` at all. Just loop over the list directly:

```
for add in purchase_amount:
    add = float(add)
    subtotal = subtotal + add
```

You can shorten the last line by using `+=` augmented assignment:

```
for add in purchase_amount:
    add = float(add)
    subtotal += add
```

You can shorten it further with the `map()` function to convert all elements to floats as you loop, and the `sum()` function to add up all the values in a sequence:

```
subtotal = sum(map(float, purchase_amount))
```